# Experience in Eberron

Tags: dnd-5e, experience-points, eberron, non-combat

I just got my copy of the Eberron Rising sourcebook and am keen to run a game. I love the idea of a noir detective style story, but it seems to me that it will revolve around a lot of role-playing and investigation, but relatively few fights.

How should I award experience in a game like this?

Comment: Some related/helpful questions: "[Why is there no non-combat XP in D&D 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101102)", "[Are there alternative ways to gain XP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53527)", and "[How to manage XP in non-combat missions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80661)"

Comment: The old fashioned way: make them earn it. 8^D.  All kidding aside, since you have not yet begun the campaign, you may be predicting a problem that you don't have.  This is kind of hard to answer for that reason among others.  I suggest that you run a few sessions, and if you then discover a problem, post that with more details on how XP awards faced you with difficulty.  Also, were the related question @Medix2 posted helpful to you?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the Dungeon Masters Guide?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## XP is awarded for completing encounters, not just fights

As a DM in 5E, you have massive freedom to craft your campaign and reward players as you see fit. Even when working from a source book such as Eberron, you can adjust encounters as you see fit to add to the story or present additional challenge.

XP was never designed as only a combat reward, but rather, a reward for your PCs overcoming an obstacle to their adventure goal. This can be outright defeat of an enemy in combat, roleplay encounters, puzzle-solving, political machinations; anything your players come up with to address a problem. Your role in PC progression is to determine the difficulty of these problems, and to reward the PCs with the appropriate degree of "growth" for having overcome them; this growth is represented as Experience Points.

In short, the simple answer is: "Award experience however you like!"

Comment: I'd suggest also including a reference to the DMG where how to award experience is addressed.   You may want to borrow some content from this [excellent answer to a similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/101104/22566)

Comment: Guess I'd better read the DMG again ;)